# Some VM's can Ping a Server, but other VM's can't

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, connection, ping, hyper-v

We have a collection of VM's, each one is hosted on Server1, all of them need to be able to connect to/ping Server2.

- VM1 can ping Serevr2
- VM2 can ping Server2
- VM3 cant ping Server2
- VM4 cant ping Serevr2

All the Internet Connection Properties are the same. There is nothing different as far as I can tell.

Comment: How about a network architecture? Or perhaps more information of any kind? This is not a lot to go on.

Comment: Basically we have used the PortQuery Tool to check whether there is connectivity between the VM's hosted on our Server and a Clients Server. Some of the VM's reported a connection, others didnt. This has worked for the past year I would just like suggestions on what could have happened to remove the connectivity to just a few of these VM's

Answer (score 0):

As @prateek61 has said, some more information would be helpful.

- is each server within the same network?
- lan segments between server1 & 2?
- vlans?
- vpn's?
- correctly configured IPs/DNS/default routes, etc.

It could be as simple as kernel/driver changes within the VM being incompatible.

1. have each vm check it can ping the host e.g. Server1.
2. ping test to router
3. ping test to external google.com.au
4. further items could include things like checking firewalls

You mention:

```
All the Internet Connection Properties are the same
```

I presume this wouldn't include duplicate MAC's across the virtual NIC's?

For a business, I would expect this to have already been done as some fairly basic network diagnosis?